# How many ways huge data can be optimize in table sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, database-performance

i was asked in interview if there is a table with 300000000 data & 300 fields then when people search data in that table the performance will be slow. so what are the steps u like to follow to optimize the table and search data.

i just said putting many index on those fields which are often use in search clause. but the person who asked this question he was exception to have many solution to handle this situation.

here lots of experience people traverse this forum. so i am expecting many ways to handle this situation. so please guide me in details all the possible measure one need to follow. thanks

Comment: I would suggest you read a good book on performance tuning for SQl server. There are hundreds of things you can do to improve performance.

Comment: can u suggest me few books name which only talk about performance tuning for SQl server. thanks

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_fb_0_29?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=performance+tuning+sql+server&sprefix=performance+tuning+sql+server%2Cdigital-text%2C392 I would suggest the books by Sajal Dam or Grant Fritchley for the version of SQL Server you are interviewing for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At a glance I would consider:

- partioning the data
- archiving old data
- breaking the table out into related tables
- getting better hardware
- rewriting the queries to be performant
- using full text search
- and of course indexing.

Of course there are many other ways to performance tune. And many of them are specific to specific situations. This is a something that is covered in very thick books not something that can truly be answered on the Internet.

Comment: partitioning data means r u trying to table partitioning or data partitioning? please clarify. thanks

Answer (score 2):

300 columns sounds like quite a lot for one table. Perhaps the data should be [normalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) into several tables. Take note - normalization can cause performance problems itself, particularly because of large SQL joins, so perfect normalization is not always the best solution either.

Finally, once you find a possible solution or two, I would call the interviewer with your findings and ask if there was another solution that you missed.